# bitbake custom-image | do_fetch: Fetcher Failure

Tags: yocto, qt6, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer, yocto-kirkstone

I am trying to build a Linux image using Yocto, and I want to run a simple Qt6 application with it on a Raspberry Pi4.

I have an issue after starting to build ($ bitbake custom-image). It says, that my .cpp and .pro file, which I have drawn from my Qt Creator project, cannot be fetched, see error log below.

```
WARNING: qtexample-0.1-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL file://qtexample.pro, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: qtexample-0.1-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://qtexample.pro anywhere. The paths that were searched were:
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample-0.1/poky
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample/poky
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/files/poky
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample-0.1/raspberrypi4
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample/raspberrypi4
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/files/raspberrypi4
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample-0.1/armv7ve
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample/armv7ve
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/files/armv7ve
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample-0.1/rpi
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample/rpi
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/files/rpi
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample-0.1/arm
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample/arm
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/files/arm
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample-0.1/
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample/
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/files/
    /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/build-rpi/downloads
ERROR: qtexample-0.1-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'file://qtexample.pro')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/build-rpi/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtexample/0.1-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.148341
ERROR: Task (/home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample_0.1.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2501 tasks of which 2499 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample_0.1.bb:do_fetch
```

I have included the meta-qt6 layer, and the openembedded layer. All my layers are in the correct branch for yoctio version (kirkstone) and I use Qt6.5 LTS branch in meta-qt6.

My custom-image.bb file is inside /meta-custom/receipe-core/images and looks as follows:

```
SUMMARY = "Custom Linux image."

IMAGE_INSTALL = "packagegroup-core-boot ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL}"

IMAGE_LINGUAS = " "

LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit core-image

# Set rootfs to 200 MiB by default
IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR ?= "1.0"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE ?= "204800"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE:append = "${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "systemd", " + 4096", "", d)}"

# Include Qt example application
IMAGE_INSTALL += "qtexample"
```

My qtexample_0.1.bb recipe, to build the application in the layer, is located at /meta-custom/recipe-apps/qtexample/qtexample_0.1.bb and looks as follows:

```
SUMMARY = "QT Example Recipe"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://qtexample.pro \
           file://qtexample.cpp"

DEPENDS += "qtbase"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "qtwayland"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit qt6-qmake
```

Inside /qtexample, there is /qtexample/file, where my .cpp and .pro files from the Qt creator app live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, Bitbake tried a list of paths to find your file `file://qtexample.pro`, one of them is:

> /home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/files/

So, you need `files` and not `file`, you should have the following structure in your `meta-custom`:

```
meta-custom/
  `-- recipes-apps/
      `-- qtexample/
          |-- qtexample_0.1.bb
          `-- files/
              |-- qtexample.pro
              `-- qtexample.cpp
```

**NOTE 1**: Your path is incorrect:

```
.. is located at /meta-custom/recipe-apps/qtexample/qtexample_0.1.bb ..
                                   ^
                                   | HERE it should be recipes-apps
```

**NOTE 2**: Generally when having local files for your recipe, you can put them in one of the following:

- `files`: In your case: `meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/files`
- `${PN}`: In your case: `meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample`
- `${PN}-${PV}`: In your case: `meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample-0.1`

As you can see that bitbake tried those 3 paths:

```
/home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample-0.1/
/home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/qtexample/
/home/bkeohane/Projekte/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-apps/qtexample/files/
```

Other custom folder names should be added to `FILESEXTRAPATHS`, example (folder: `custom-folder`), with:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/custom-folder:"
```

Comment: Thanks.

I was not aware of the fact, that it has to be a "files" directory, and inside qtexample_0.1.bb, specify the sources with "file://...".